# Python Script to test out multiple variants of email addresses

Tags: python, django, bots

I am new to programming and Python and I am testing out an idea for emails. I want to see if I can create a Python script that will allow me to do 3 things.

1. Allow the user to Input a name and an email url.
2. Insert multiple variants of email name possibilities.
3. Send out a test email to all the variants and return of one of them worked.

For number 2, there would be an already set list of the most common variations such as(John.Smith, John-Smith, etc..)

I have figured out how to send out emails but I am having trouble with 1 and 2. I’m not sure if a simple “for loop” will work be how to set the parameters. Thanks for your help. It’s a stupid project but I’m hoping it will help me see it a little differently

Comment: For #1 , you want the user name to be input from the command line or UI?

Comment: It would be easier if you share your code and explain which parts of it you're having trouble with.

Comment: you can simply use `email = input("Choose an email:")` to get user input. For the 2., you can try regex.

Comment: Initially I am going to do it all from the terminal but I will want to move it to the UI.

Comment: I will try to post it when I get home. I’m at work on my phone at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll take a look at regex. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You mention you're trying to create a Python script, but you tagged this post with Django, so I'm going to give you two answers.

**If you're just writing a Python script:**

To accomplish #1, look into [the `input()` function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp). It'll allow you to prompt the user and take user input at the command line and then save it as a variable.

For #2, you could take the user input string and perhaps use [the `split()` method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) to separate the input by first and last name. Then, you could save the first and last name that you've obtained into variables, and then you could have an array containing the format for some of the email variants you've come up with. For instance:

```
name_input = input("Enter first and last name (ex. 'John Smith'): ")
domain_input = input("Enter an email domain (ex. 'gmail.com'): ")

name_list = user_input.split()

first_name = name_list[0]
last_name = name_list[1]
variant_list = [first_name + "-" + last_name + "@" + domain_input, first_name + "." + last_name + "@" + domain_input]
```

*NOTE: You should look into [Python string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for your variant list!*

**If you're doing this with a Django web app:**

To accomplish #1, you'll need to take user input through [some sort of HTML form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/). Then your backend can handle parsing the data in the request sent by the form, similar to how the Python script above does using `split()`.

For #2, you can do the same as shown above!

**For both:**

Regarding #3, I suggest using a for loop through the list of variants you make in order to send those emails (which you've already figured out how to do).